# Local martingale from weak solution to SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $X,\{\mathcal F_t\}$ be a weak solution to the SDE
$$dX_t=b(X_t)\,dt+\sigma(X_t)\,dWt$$
where $b_i:\Bbb R^d\rightarrow \Bbb R$, $W$ is a $r$-dimensional Brownian motion and $\sigma_{ij}:\Bbb R^d\rightarrow \Bbb R$ for $1\leq i\leq d$, $1\leq j\leq r$.

Let $a_{ik}(x)=\sum_{j=1}^r\sigma_{ij}(x)\sigma_{kj}(x)$ for $1\leq i,k\leq d$, and for $f:\Bbb R^d\rightarrow\Bbb R$ twice continuously differentiable, define
$$\mathscr Af(x)=\sum_{i=1}^db_i(x)\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^d\sum_{k=1}^da_{ik}(x)\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}$$

For a progressively measurable and locally integrable process $\{k_t,\mathcal F_t\}$, and $f:\Bbb R^d\rightarrow\Bbb R$ twice continuously differentiable, define
 $$\Lambda_t:=f(X_t)e^{-\int_0^tk_u\,du}-f(X_0)-\int_0^t(\mathscr Af(X_s)-k_sf(X_s))e^{-\int_0^sk_u\,du}\,ds$$
I am trying to show that $\Lambda,\{\mathcal F_t\}$ is a continuous local martingale (this is Problem 4.34 of *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*). I am not sure how I should approach this problem. I can apply Ito on $f(X_t)$ to see that
$$M_t:=f(X_t)-f(X_0)-\int_0^t\mathscr Af(X_s)\,ds$$
is a continuous local martingale. However I don't see how to treat the terms such as $f(X_t)e^{-\int_0^tk_u\,du}$ appearing in $\Lambda_t$. I can't use the product rule for this either, because that will require the covariation $[f(X_t),e^{-\int_0^tk_u\,du}]$ which doesn't seem possible to compute. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $e^{-\int_0^t k_u du}$ is a BV process, so that cross-variation you wrote at the end is just 0.

Comment: @JasonSwanson Why is it BV?

Comment: Because $k$ is locally integrable, so it is the exponential of a BV process.